# Do I have right to delay the increase of my rent by one month if the landlord proposes to increase it on Febraury the 30th?

Tags: rent, mutual-mistake

This is the text of the e-mail I received from the agency on 28th of January (my emphasis):

> Hello,
>
> I hope this finds you well.
>
> Unfortunately, we’ve been asked to inform you of an increase in your rent. It hasn’t been increased in a while, and our landlord would like to have a fair return on his property whilst recognising that you have been a good tenant for a long time. He’s asked us to increase the rent to £500 from the existing £470.
>
> You are entitled to one month’s notice of any increase, so this won’t come into effect ***until your rent due date on 30th February 2022***. Once agreed, your rent cannot be reviewed for another 12 months.
>
> Please see the attached form for details, and do let me know if you have any questions or concerns about this rise.
>
> Kind regards,

and also the form attached to the e-mail, signed by the landlord's agent, contains the same mistake:

> The starting date for the new rent will be
>
> 30/02/2022

Do I have any right to interpret that as "not-in-February", and to increase the payment on the next month?

---

It's clearly a typo, right. But what should I assume that *30/02/2022* was meant to be *28/02/2022* and not *30/03/2022*? Both typos are equally likely, no?

Comment: I am guessing that is just a typo and not thinking about the number of days in February, I would suggest reaching out to the landlord to get them to clarify as it would be silly to risk late fees and other penalties for not paying

Comment: @JoeW, yes, it's clearly a typo. But on the document that requires me to pay. Going OT in this comment, I think it would be fair for them to accept they've made a gross mistake and spare me one single month of rent :D

Comment: And if they decide to charge you late fees for the extra amount you didn't pay? A typo in the date doesn't change the fact that they gave you one months notice to this or entitle you to an extra month at the old rate.

Comment: When did you receive the notice? If it was today, then even a fictional 30 FEB is not one month’s notice. It would have to be end of March since today is end of February, or at least 28 March, no?

Comment: I received the notice one month ago, which is in line with the interpretation of _30/02 was meant to be 28/02_

Comment: What was the date of the email? And when did you "first read it"?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore., January the 13th.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I have any right to interpret that as "not-in-February", and to increase the payment on the next month?

No. The letter is clear in that it serves as a one-month notice for rent increase (I'm assuming that the timing of the letter complies with your entitlement to the notice).

Even the [doctrine of contra proferentem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra_proferentem) would be unavailing because *contra proferentem* is about adopting from among *reasonable* interpretations the one that is favorable to the non-draftsman. No reasonable interpretation can be premised on an unreal date such as the 30th of February.

Comment: Why should I assume that in _30th of February_ the mistake is in the day and not in the month?

Comment: The part in the letter referring to one month's notice (not two month's notice) establishes the reasonable objective interpretation over the alternative "*March* 30".

Comment: As OP clarified: the document is 1 month old by now.